# Is it necessary to test the BOOL finished in a completion handler for UIView animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I've never given any thought to the returned `BOOL finished` of a UIView animation completion handler, but reading some sample code in the Apple UIView Programming Guide shows this:

```
completion:^(BOOL finished) {
 if (finished) {
```

Is this necessary? The completion block shouldn't run unless the animation has finished anyway, right? The test seems redundant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual action being undertaken in that code snippet is quite significant. The animation is transitioning from one view to another -- the first is being replaced, and then a boolean is set to keep track of which one is currently displayed. The boolean is set in the completion block.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:(displayingPrimary ? primaryView : secondaryView)
    toView:(displayingPrimary ? secondaryView : primaryView)
    duration:1.0
    options:(displayingPrimary ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight :
                UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft)
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
            displayingPrimary = !displayingPrimary;
        }
}];
```

In this case, if the animation (for whatever reason) doesn't complete, then the views haven't been exchanged, and you absolutely don't want to flip the value of `displayingPrimary`, because you'll then have an inaccurate record of your status. That's why the `finished` flag is checked in this case.

Notice that in most (if not all) of the other code samples in that guide, the flag isn't checked -- that's because it's not significant in those cases (running another animation after the first, e.g., or changing some value that *doesn't* depend on the successful completion of the animation).

Comment: so it sounds like a completion block can in fact run even if the bool finished is zero. why would that happen? since it is a "completion" block, wouldnt it only run if the prior block did in fact complete?

Comment: Starting a new animation with one of those methods, there's an option to have the new one interrupt the first. There's also an option to allow user interaction with the view, which may present an opportunity to cancel the animation.

Comment: According to doc the transitionFromView add the toView at the BEGINNING of the animation and get fromView out of superView at the END of the animation. Does that mean if finished is false than BOTH fromView and toView is still there? Because in my cases, I've seen cases where both are gone.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you really should honor that bool in your handler.  The user might initiate the animation, but before that animation completes normally, the user does something else to cancel it early.  This bool well let you know of such cases.

-- update --
Just to elaborate.  Imagine some animation that moves a view across the screen. The handler might fire when the view is done moving.  Suppose the user touches somewhere else to cause a new animation that essentially cancels this first one in progress. You could use the provided bool to detect that.

Comment: Are you suggesting that even if the animation is cancelled, the completion handler might still run?

Comment: Hopefully somebody will chime in who is more confident than I am on this, but yes, I think that is the case.  Not canceled before it is ever run, but interrupted before it could go to completion.

Comment: The completion block has only a meaning and you should validate and use it only if you need to do something specific after the animation completed successfully. If you don't care what happens with the animation, then there is no point on validating if the animation completed successfully...