# animateWithDuration: delay: API usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

In the header file for `UIView`, I see this API.

```
+(void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                     delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
                   options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
                animations:(void (^)(void))animations
                completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

In it's a completion block, why is the `(BOOL finished)` parameter passed to the block?
In my limited testing it is always `TRUE`.
When can it be false?

Comment: Find the answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410104/is-it-necessary-to-test-the-bool-finished-in-a-completion-handler-for-uiview-ani?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @Greg : also flag the question as duplicate